# How can we make websites as responsive as Amazon?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, tachyons-css

I am challenging myself with small project in ReactJs and [Tachyons](http://tachyons.io) to produce a website as responsive as Amazon (front-end only).

Here is an example of what Amazon can do and I haven't been able to achieve.

**Here is Amazon page in full width**
[image]

**Amazon's page in half width**. Here we can see that Amazon was responsive and changed the size of the search bar.
[image]

**Amazon's website in minimum browser size.**Here the website remained at **the same** size as when it was in half width. 
[image]

If you want to try with your web browser, [access Amazon](https://amazon.co.uk)

I tried to do the same and I tried a lot of things unsuccessfully, so here is me asking for help.

Currently I am using [React-Device-Detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect) to detect type of devices. Instead of making the website responsive, I do the same job twice in a row (once for the website and once for the mobile with different sizes, etc.) I suppose that the same thing is done by Amazon? (check Amazon on your phone, on your PC, then also check Amazon on your PC with minimum width and see that it differs from your phone)

Now the problem I have in the pictures below:

**Website in full page**
[image]

**Website in minimum page**. We can observe that everything is resized, the blue bar has decreased in height, the 5 columns are looking terrible 
[image]

Should I use Bootstrap and is it my only solution? Is Amazon using Bootstrap or do they have their own 'css framework'?

Comment: Frameworks make your life easier but don't do anything that you can't do manually... After all, some other person made bootstrap...

Comment: the same issue here: 4k> support.  I was only able to find some  add-on for bootstrap  that partial work  https://github.com/thunderblaster/bootstrap-xxl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many solutions about your problem depending on your goals.

1. [CSS media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
2. A CSS framework (eg. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/))
3. A React component library (eg. [React Material UI](https://material-ui.com/))

My first personal recommendation would be the **[Material UI Grid](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/) component**. It's really easy to be implemented and it does a good work! Totally recommended for a react beginner developer.

A second option would be **CSS media queries along with styled-components**. It's a little bit more advanced technique but it results in more clean code.

Hint: You can also check [muuri](https://github.com/haltu/muuri) UI library.

Comment: Material UI Grid looks like what I was looking for. I will also try Bootstrap first, because I see it is recommended by many, and in case I am not satisfied with it go with your recommendation
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, Amazon's website is not fully responsive. I should never have to scroll horizontally. Nevertheless, you can attain this a couple of ways.

**Bootstrap or Foundation: Responsive Libraries**

You can install Bootstrap or Foundation into your project. These libraries do all of the responsive work for you (for the most part some exceptions here and there which you can fix with media queries).

The documentation for both libraries are incredible and you can learn each library with the documentation alone. But, there are plenty of free resources to learn them (Bootstrap especially). I would not pay to learn either.

I have listed some resources for Bootstrap below (it's what I've always used and prefer so I know more about it).

**Bootstrap Resources**: Here are just a few resources for Bootstrap

1. Bootstrap's website: https://getbootstrap.com/
2. w3 Schools website: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp
   You can walk through their tutorial for Bootstrap. That link is to a table that contains all of the bootstrap classes and demos for each.
3. Youtube: you can look up tutorials on youtube. I won't recommend any specific video but you can find one that works best for you.

I recommend completing a front-end web page with just HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap (sort of a template for your react site) to get the feel for Bootstrap first.

To incorporate with ReactJS, you can install just bootstrap with: `npm i bootstrap` but you won't get the dropdown, popover, tooltip, etc., functionality. This is where packages like `react-bootstrap` and `reactstrap` come in. They give you the functionality and responsiveness.

**CSS Media Queries**

You can set up media queries for specific page widths or screen sizes. This is a very tedious task and if you try to apply this to every element of your website you will have a lot of CSS code to write and manage.

Example: This says, for any screen that is 720px wide or smaller, apply this background to the body of the site.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  body {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
}
```

Obviously, this can become a lot more complex. You can put any CSS and target any classnames within the `@media` curly braces. So, you do not have to just put `body`.

Hope this helps.

Update:

> Instead of making the website responsive, I do the same job twice in a
>   row (once for the website and once for the mobile with different
>   sizes, etc.) I suppose that the same thing is done by Amazon?

Also, I'm not sure what exactly you want for mobile but you should not have to create anything separate for mobile. That's the point of responsive. Everything in today's world is responsive and really, a lot of things are "mobile first" (lot of debate around that though) so you really should do responsive. Using the responsive libraries or queries will do all of that work for you. So you would not need **React Device Detect**. The libraries have media queries already set up for virtually every screen size (support for 4k is light or nonexistent). This means that when you visit your site on a cell phone it will automatically adjust.

If you want a *mobile application*, that's something completely different. Amazon has that as well. You can use **React Native** for that and probably adapt much of your web app source for that mobile app.

Hope that was clear.

Comment: Dear Bens Steves, thanks for your answer. Actually you mentioned something very important. The fact that you have to scroll horizontally is not responsive, however have a look in Google Chrome > Inspect > from the top right, select "iPhone X". Now the website appears entirely in the given width. I would like to do pretty much the same, should I still use Bootstrap?

Comment: just checked that. That is quite strange. They have to be using a responsive library...right??? lol that's really weird. They must have specific media queries for their entire site....I just can't believe that. But you're right when you go into responsive mode with the dev tools and does readjust....very strange

Comment: and yes Bootstrap or foundation will do all of that work for you.

Comment: you can look up a bootstrap free template or a foundation free template and play around with it. you will see it adapt in the dev tools without you having to do much. that's why so many people love those libraries cuts out a bunch of the work, time, and writing :)

Comment: sorry for all of these comments but i am now consumed by amazon's website :) it looks like they might be migrating over to a responsive library...I only say that because their toggle button on the top left looks like it is straight from Bootstrap's library....wow. Amazon? I'm dumbfounded. anywho...best of luck to you. If you have any more questions please ask :)

Comment: Hahaha can understand the excitement! Thanks again for the help

Comment: no problem. I went into a deep dive on their site and it's just atrocious. I can't believe it. I need to step away from it...but I can't unsee it :) Anyways...glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use some css framework that is mobile friendly(first), they are all responsive designed. Bootstrap is a very popular one.